# Writing inline HTML elements in JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, ecmascript-6

this.selectedDashboard.data.name is a promise returned in json string format which is equal to the selected dash name. (ex: name: 'my dashboard' ). so how do i make it bold or strong on the fly without messing with html file. frankly , i kind of dont have access to the html file.

so the output for this.sialertdialog would be like : are you sure you want to remove **my dashboard** ? This operation cannot be undone!

```js
deleteDashboard = () => {
        let dashname = this.selectedDashboard.data.name;
        console.log(dashname);
        this.siAlertDialog.confirm(this.$filter('translate')('SI-MESSAGES.DELETE-DASHBOARDMSG') + dashname +' ?'+ ' This operation cannot be undone!')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.$filter('translate')('SI-MESSAGES.DELETE-DASHBOARDMSG') +"<strong>"+ dashname +'</strong> ? This operation cannot be undone!'
```

You can embed html even if you havent access to the html...

Comment: see thats what i thought we can do , but in the view its showing............. Are you sure you want to remove the dashboard: <strong>my Dashboard</strong> ? This operation cannot be undone!

Comment: hopefully this is the write way to code .,......        this.siAlertDialog.confirm(this.$filter('translate')('SI-MESSAGES.DELETE-DASHBOARDMSG') + "<strong>"+ dashname +"</strong>" +' ?'+ ' This operation cannot be undone!')

Comment: @AnuRajan that must have todo with the siAlertDialog. I havent done anything with that, may have a look into its docs...

Comment: will check the doc relate to siaLERT